# Google Play Alert- App using unsafe implementation of the hostnameVerifier

Tags: android, android-studio

I got a security alert from google play when I upload an APK to play store below.
Your App is using the unsafe implementation of the HostnameVerifier Interface.
My code is here.

```
public class NukeSSLCerts {
    protected static final String TAG = "NukeSSLCerts";

    public static void nuke() {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustManagerArr = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509CertificateArr, String str) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509CertificateArr, String str) {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
            }};
            SSLContext instance = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            instance.init(null, trustManagerArr, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(instance.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public  boolean verify(String str, SSLSession sSLSession) {
                    return true;

                }
            });
        } catch (Exception unused) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepting all SSL certificates is usually not the ideal scenario. Slightly better is to only accept your specific SSL certificate using this code snippet.

```
 final class CustomTrust {



   private static InputStream trustedCertificatesInputStream() {
    String certificate_one = "ADD_YOUR_CERTIFICATE";
    String certificate_two = "ADD_YOUR_CERTIFICATE";

    return new Buffer()
            .writeUtf8(certificate_one)
            .writeUtf8(certificate_two)
            .inputStream();
     }

      public static X509TrustManager getTrustManagerForCertificates()
        throws GeneralSecurityException {

    InputStream in= trustedCertificatesInputStream();
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = 
    CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = 
    certificateFactory.generateCertificates(in);
    if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted 
    certificates");
    }

    // Put the certificates a key store.
    char[] password = "password".toCharArray(); // Any password will work.
    KeyStore keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
    int index = 0;
    for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
        String certificateAlias = Integer.toString(index++);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
    }

    // Use it to build an X509 trust manager.
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
            KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof 
     X509TrustManager)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
                + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
    }
    return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
}

private static KeyStore newEmptyKeyStore(char[] password) throws 
     GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream in = null; // By convention, 'null' creates an empty key 
         store.
        keyStore.load(in, password);
        return keyStore;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}}
```

Use this CustomTrust in your OKHttp Client as.

```
  public class MyOkHttpClient {
  public static OkHttpClient get(Context context) {
    try {

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager


    X509TrustManager trustManager = 
   CustomTrust.getTrustManagerForCertificates();
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = 
      sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new 
         OkHttpClient.Builder()

                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)

                .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)


        return okHttpBuilder.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} }
```

Comment: Is this security approved by Google ?

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa currently I am following this link and searching about valid answers approved by google. Meanwhile, if you have some other authentic solution please share it with us.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired